# How can i send simple text to another computer in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, server

Basically all i want to do is have one exe file, on a main computer (windows), start listening over the net for another exe file on another computer (also windows) to send a simple string of text, in which the main computer will receive the text, display it, and then from there i'll be able to figure out what i want to do with it.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: There are so many examples of this to be found if you search a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending data over a network like so at a low level we use something called sockets to send a TCP message. On Windows the standard API for this is [Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock). On a Unix-based computer like MacOS or Linux you'd use [Unix Sockets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html). I'm much more familiar with Unix sockets than Windows ones so I won't be much help to you on the specifics but the Microsoft docs are generally very informative and should get you started.

Be warned that low level socket programming is not at all a very beginner-friendly programming paradigm. There are third party higher level APIs for c++ that may be easier to use, but quite honestly for most applications I'd just recommend using Golang or C# (Dotnet) for networking applications as both are very similar in functionality to C++ and have much more intuitive interfaces to send TCP messages over a network built into the language.

Comment: thank you very much. idk how, but your answer led me to find a website that explains this subject in a lot more detail than what i found before. i did do research and tried to say that i did (and more information!) in the question but it got removed for not being specific. i found many posts that were not all too helpful and kind of confusing, but i think i finally found one after seeing your answer that fits my needs. i had heard about winsock, but was not finding very introduction-level information on it. thanks again. kind regards - a new user with a bad first question.

Comment: Good luck! This really isn't a beginner topic at all, hence my recommendation for another language for something like this. Even with another language networking can be tricky for beginners. I'm really sorry about the hostile environment that greeted you here, the site can be really quite brutal sometimes to beginners. For the record I thought your question was perfectly fine and totally something I would have asked a few years ago. Don't let them discourage you!